# How to deal with exceptions in Scala Futures?

Tags: scala, future

I implemented a simple job processor that processes subjobs within futures (scala.actors.Futures). These futures themselves can create more futures for processing subjobs. Now, if one of these subjobs throws an exception, i want the job processor to reply with an error message for that job. I have a workaround solution for discovering failed subjobs, but i'm not sure if that's the best solution. Basically it works like this:

```
sealed trait JobResult
case class SuccessResult(content: String) extends JobResult
case class FailedResult(message: String) extends JobResult

for(subjob <- subjobs) yield {
  future {
    try {
          SuccessResult(process(subjob))
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => FailedResult(e.getMessage)                              
    }
  }
}
```

The result at the top level is a recursive List of Lists of Lists... of JobResults. I recursively search the List for a failed Result and then return an error or the combined result depending on the types of results. 
That works but i'm wondering if there's is a more elegant/easier solution for dealing with exceptions in futures?

Answer (score 5):

The way you do it now, is essentially what scala.Either was designed for. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Either.html

Comment: Yep, use Either, or even better, Validation from scalaz.

Comment: Thx, will have a look at both suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

Modern scala futures *are* like `Either` in that they contain either a successful result or a `Throwable`. If you re-visit this code in scala 2.10, i think you'll find the situation quite pleasant.

Specifically, [scala.concurrent.Future[T]](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) technically only "is-a" `Awaitable[T]`, but `_.onComplete` and `Await.ready(_, timeout).value.get` both present its result as a [scala.util.Try[T]](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try), which is a lot like `Either[Throwable, T]` in that it's either the result or an exception.

Oddly, `_.transform` takes two mapping functions, one for `T => U` and one for `Throwable => Throwable` and (unless i'm missing something) there's no transformer that maps the future as `Try[T] => Try[U]`. `Future`'s `.map` will allow you to turn a success into a failure by simply throwing an exception in the mapping function, but it only uses that for successes of the original `Future`. Its `.recover`, similarly can turn a failure into a success. If you wanted to be able to change successes to failures and vice-versa, you'd need to build something yourself that was a combination of `_.map` and `_.recover` or else use `_.onComplete` to chain to a new [scala.concurrent.Promise[U]](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise) like so:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

def flexibleTransform[T,U](fut: Future[T])(f: Try[T] => Try[U])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[U] = {
  val p = Promise[U]
  fut.onComplete { res =>
    val transformed = f(res)
    p.complete(transformed)
  }
  p.future
}
```

which would be used like so:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf

def doIt() {
  val a: Future[Integer] = Future {
    val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt
    if (r % 2 == 0) {
      throw new Exception("we don't like even numbers")
    } else if (r % 3 == 0) {
      throw new Exception("we don't like multiples of three")
    } else {
      r
    }
  }

  val b: Future[String] = flexibleTransform(a) {
    case Success(i) =>
      if (i < 0) {
        // turn negative successes into failures
        Failure(new Exception("we don't like negative numbers"))
      } else {
        Success(i.toString)
      }
    case Failure(ex) =>
      if (ex.getMessage.contains("three")) {
        // nevermind about multiples of three being a problem; just make them all a word.
        Success("three")
      } else {
        Failure(ex)
      }
  }

  val msg = try {
    "success: " + Await.result(b, Inf)
  } catch {
    case t: Throwable =>
      "failure: " + t
  }
  println(msg)
}

for { _ <- 1 to 10 } doIt()
```

which would give something like this:

```
failure: java.lang.Exception: we don't like even numbers
failure: java.lang.Exception: we don't like negative numbers
failure: java.lang.Exception: we don't like negative numbers
success: three
success: 1756800103
failure: java.lang.Exception: we don't like even numbers
success: 1869926843
success: three
failure: java.lang.Exception: we don't like even numbers
success: three
```

(or you could "pimp" `Future` into a `RichFutureWithFlexibleTransform` with an implicit def and make `flexibleTransform` a member function of that, dropping the `fut` param and simply using `this`)

(even better would be to take `Try[T] => Future[U]` and call it `flexibleFlatMap` so you could do async things in the transform)

Comment: You may want to mention the type: [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try)